IIS deploy clickOnce application Assembly.LoadFrom https File Error
I deployed a ClickOnce program using IIS. The program will access the resource DLL from the network for Assembly.LoadFrom(https://xxxxx/xx.exe)

An error occurredThe security credentials required to access this resource are invalid. (Exception occurred in HRESULT: 0x800C0019

(I'm not sure what the actual English error message is)
But when I use WebClient.DownloadFile(https://xxxxx/xx.exe), it works normally
This problem only occurs when using https and specific environments.
Some environments using http and https can run normally.
I would like to ask if there is any way to try to troubleshoot this problem?
